# Have the Westworld producers acknowledged the similarities between Westworld season 3 and Person of Interest

Tags: westworld-2016, person-of-interest

Season 3 of Westworld contains the idea of the human race being controlled by an artificial intelligence, Rehoboam. This AI identifies individuals that need to be removed in order to protect the human race.

This is remarkably similar to the Samaritan AI that is a protagonist of the later seasons of Person of Interest. An AI that is designed to predict human behavior so individuals can be eliminated before they perform actions deemed to be against the goals of Samaritan.

There are other similarities, the images depicting "Anomalies" in parts of the globe, lining up with the Hosts are very similar to the way Person of Interest used CCTV to highlight types of individuals.

The same production team are involved in creating both series, have Nolan, Abrams or Bryan Burk discussed the links between the 2 at all I am always interested in if these kinds of similarities in someones work are intended and a something that was very much planned and intended, or more subconscious. To me it feels like Westworld could be the same universe as Person of Interest with the work of Ford, Arthur, Serec and his brother being a continuation of the work started by Harold Finch.